# ggplotly removes names from ggpairs

Tags: r, plotly

I'm using ggplotly to convert a scatterplot matrix (made with GGally::ggpairs) into a plotly object.  Some aspects of the plot seem to be lost in translation...for instance the names of the variables being plotted show up fine when using ggpairs along...However, wrapping it in plotly renders the matrix but without the variables names.

Here's a working example of the plotly scatterplot without names:

```
library(GGally)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlotly({
    pm <- GGally::ggpairs(iris, lower = list(combo = "box")) %>% ggplotly()
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("scatterplot", height = 700)
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```